# Opening CallKit with VoIP on iOS 14.2 is not working in killed state

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, tokbox

I'm using Tokbox with CallKit. I have two applications: Doctor and Patient. Doctor is going to call Patient through Tokbox with CallKit. If the application is in killed state on iOS 14.2, it will not receive the VoIP notification and so the call will not start. With lower iOS versions it's working fine. Is anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Plz checking again your VOIP certificate rightly configure or not...
Then plz check with your backend server...

Comment: I understand that this is your first answer but please focus on giving more accurate and descriptive answers : )